# Threads piling up in Jboss (wildfly) leading to unresponsiveness

Tags: java, jboss, wildfly, thread-dump

I am running WildFly Full 14.0.1.Final (WildFly Core 6.0.2.Final)
I am seeing gradual increase in thread count in my thread dump, which I take every 15 minutes
Most of the stacktraces read as below:
I need a clarification here. Looking at the stacktrace, the thread seems to be waiting for a task, which is normal.  But I can also see that it is waiting on another thread **0x00007f8e16441000**

```
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET| "default task-94" #409 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000042ae800 nid=0x32a5 waiting on condition [0x00007f8e16441000]
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@9/Native Method)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000400e553c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET| "default task-93" #408 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000041af000 nid=0x32a4 waiting on condition [0x00007f8e170c3000]
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|    java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(java.base@9/Native Method)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        - parking to wait for  <0x0000000400e553c8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
2019-11-09 16:30:06 CET|        at java.lang.Thread.run(java.base@9/Unknown Source)
```

Should I have to investigate on 
(a) why jboss is not closing these threads which are existing over multiple days 
or 
(b) drill down to the thread dump which has the thread on which other threads are waiting on.

If it is (a), please let me know where/what to look for.

Otherwise i did not make any changes to thread params in standalone-full.xml

much thanks

Comment: Hi , did you ever find a solution to this? I am having the exact same issue!